# WebRTC adapter.js returns empty object

Tags: angularjs, html, webrtc

I am building a WebRTC app with the front-end emplyong [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) and AngularJS.
A call to the function **getUserMedia** from adapter.js the success handler returns an empty object as the stream object. Below is a snippet of the code.

**index.html**

```
        <video class="online" id='local-video' autoplay ng-src="{{localVideoStream}}"></video>
```

**main.js**

```
$scope.constraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: true
};
$scope.localVideoStream = null;

getUserMedia($scope.constraints, function(stream) {
    socket.emit('message:webrtc', stream);
    console.log(stream);
    $scope.localVideoStream = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(stream);
    handleUserMedia(stream);
}, function(error) {
    $timeout(function() {
        MainService.viewport = 'main';
        $location.path('/main');
    }, 1);
    console.log(error);
});


function handleUserMedia(stream) {
   // as defined in adapter.js
}
```

Due to this behaviour I am unable to stream the local media in the video element  as shown in the index.html file.
Any way out?